# string to byte array (to string to XML) and back again

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, arrays

i know there are 1million questions about "string - byte array" conversion out there but none of them fit my problem.

For the installation of my software i need to save some informations from the user (serveraddress, userID, password and so on). Some of these informations need do be protected (encrypted using DPAPI). For that i have to convert the `string` (`SecureString`) to `byte[]`

```
public static byte[] StringToByte(string s)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(s);
}
```

where i get my first problem. If the strings lenght is a not a multiple of 4 (`s.lenght % 4 == 0`) i get a "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array" error. I've read that i can (have to) add "=" to the end of the `string` but some of these strings may be passwords (which may contain "="). I need to store the (encrypted) data in a XML-file why i can't use Unicode encoding (i don't know why but it corrupts the XML file ... because of encoding i would suppose).

As last step i have to go back the way to get the stored data on app startup.

Does someone of you can help me solving this problem ? I don't care the output in the XML as long as it is "readable".

best regards Alex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where i get my first problem. If the strings lenght is a not a multiple of 4 (s.lenght % 4 == 0) i get a "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array" error.

That suggests that it's not base64 to start with. It sounds like you're going in the wrong direction here - base64 is used to convert *binary* data into text. To convert *text* into a binary form, you should normally just use `Encoding.GetBytes`:

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

Now if you needed to encode the result of the encryption (which will be binary data) as text, *then* you'd use base64. (Because the result of encrypting UTF-8-encoded text is *not* UTF-8-encoded text.)

So something like:

```
public static string EncryptText(string input)
{
    byte[] unencryptedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = EncryptBytes(unencryptedBytes); // Not shown here
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}

public static string DecryptText(string input)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    byte[] unencryptedBytes = DecryptBytes(encryptedBytes); // Not shown here
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unencryptedBytes);
}
```

Comment: sorry to bother you jon but i have a pending question related to an old post of yours where you said(and since then i have taken that as a rule),that the saffest way to convert textual data to and from byte[] is using base64,you meant in all scenarios or just some? sorry again.

Comment: public static string ByteToString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }

        public static byte[] StringToByte(string s)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        }

tried this, but if i use it `string s = ByteToString(StringToByte("test"));` the result is "dGVzdA==" which is obviously not "test"

Comment: @Alex: Well yes, because now you're still converting from bytes to a string with `Convert.ToBase64String`! Use `Encoding.GetString` to reverse the operation of `Encoding.GetBytes`.

Comment: @terrybozzio: No - if you're *starting* with arbitrary binary data, you use Base64 to get to text, and you can get back to the same binary data that way. If you're *starting* with text data, use a normal encoding such as UTF-8.

Comment: ok, do i understand you correct, i have to start with `Encoding.UTF8` because it's "string input" then i have to encrypt it and go back to string with `Convert.ToBase64String` bacause it's now "raw binary" and vice versa to get my saved datas ?

Comment: ok, that was my mistake, i thought i use the same encoding all the time. thanks a lot

Comment: @Alex: Do you understand *why* you should use a different encoding in the two different cases? If not, it's worth thinking about it further. It's basically a matter of determining the encoding based on the type of the original data.